# sliding the whole view

Tags: objective-c

```
 i placed UITextField at the bottom of the iphone screen...
```

when i try to enter the text inside,it hides by the default keyboard..
now i want to move the whole screen when i editing the UITextField..
 is there any delegate function available to do that?
 please anyone help me.
 thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this link you find the sample for how to hide and show keyboard http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html. Now little work you need to do. hope this will help you :-).